# Межсайтовая авторизация PHP

Tags: php

есть два сайта example.com и example-login.com.
Нужно реализовать такой способ авторизации:

- С example.com перебрасывает пользователя на example-login.com. Там обрабатываются данные, запускается сессия и перебрасывает на example.com уже авторизованного пользователя.

Вопрос: как получить сессию с сайта авторизации на example.com?
И вообще возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

С сессией вряд ли получится, попробуйте использовать куки, например, сделать реализацию jwt токена. Надеюсь поможет.